# How to replace params in react router 6?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to familiarise myself with react router 6. Not a fan of it so far. I think this dynamic relative/absolute thing just makes it more complicated and vulnerable.

I'm upgrading from v5, and I was able to replace params without explicitly knowing the current path like:

```
const LinkReplaceItemId = ({ itemId }) => {
  const { path } = useRouteMatch();
  const params = useParams();

  return (
    <Link to={generatePath(path, { ...params, itemId })}>Link</Link>
  )  
}
```

There was no need to specify a pattern for the route match, it just matched whatever the current path is, and replaced the required params.

Now I have to specify the pattern to get the current path. What if I don't know the pattern - the component can be child of different route structures?

Consider the case where this can be used in:

- /items/:itemId
- /users/:userId/items/:itemId
- /collections/:itemId/properties

Just made up some examples to show an example where I want to keep the current url, just want to replace a specific piece.

How to do that in react router 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this but it would require using an externally declared array of route path patterns that can be matched. Use the `matchPath` utility to iterate the array of patterns and compare against the current `location.pathname` value. Once you have the correct path pattern you can generate the new path and override the path params.

Example:

```
import {
  useLocation,
  useParams,
  generatePath,
  Link,
  matchPath
} from "react-router-dom";

const routes = [
  "/items/:itemId",
  "/users/:userId/items/:itemId",
  "/collections/:itemId/properties"
];

const LinkReplaceItemId = ({ itemId }) => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  const pathPattern = routes.find((pattern) => matchPath(pattern, pathname));
  const params = useParams();

  return <Link to={generatePath(pathPattern, { ...params, itemId })}>Link</Link>;
};
```

[image: Edit how-to-replace-params-in-react-router-6]

Comment: @GergőHorváth I'll admit I didn't like RR6 at first either as it was ***such*** a drastic change from previous versions, but as I learned v6 and *unlearned* v5 and gained proficiency I don't miss much from v5 that didn't carry forward into v6. I think RR6 is fantastic.